# How to delete a character after a certain character

Tags: java, string, jtextfield, calculator

I am making this calculator and would like to delete everything after the equal sign and I have no Idea how
this is what I have so far :

```
ansField.getText().indexOf("=");
```

I really have no Idea after this

Comment: Review `String` manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should point you in the right direction.

`indexOf` will return the position of the `=` character in the String.  You must use this expression (+1) as the sole argument to the [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) method.

It would be best to assign this expression once to a `String` then perform your operations.

```
   String value = ansField.getText();
   String modifiedValue = value.//Do substring using indexOf
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [String.replaceAll(String, String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to find the `=` sign and replace everything afterwards. Or you could use [String.substring(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to create a substring from the first character up to and including the `=` sign.

There are many ways to do what you ask. You should look into the docs and find what works best for your case.